# How to filter by ids together with filter fields value?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to add additional filter to match `category` values in `blog.post.notes` all fields? First I want to filter by ids, then filter notes category, is it possible?

I can filter only by ids:

```
GET posts/posts/_search?fields=_id&_source=blog.post.notes
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "ids": {
          "values": [
            "100000000001234"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to filter e.g. "test" category from current results:

```
{
  "took": 58,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "posts",
      "_type": "posts",
      "_id": "100000000001234",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "blog": {
          "post": {
            "notes": {
              "main": [{
                "message": "blablabla",
                "category": "test"
              }, {
                "message": "blablabla",
                "category": "other"
              }],
              "cart": [{
                "message": "blablabla",
                "category": "test"
              }, {
                "message": "blablabla",
                "category": "other"
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

curl -XGET localhost:9200/posts/_mapping/posts

```
{
  "posts": {
    "mappings": {
      "posts": {
        "dynamic_templates": [{
          "blog": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "analyzed"
            },
            "path_match": "blog.*",
            "path_unmatch": "*.medias.*"
          }
        }, {
          "ids": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match": "_id|base_id",
            "match_pattern": "regex"
          }
        }],
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "query": {
            "properties": {
              "filtered": {
                "properties": {
                  "filter": {
                    "properties": {
                      "ids": {
                        "properties": {
                          "values": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "query": {
                    "properties": {
                      "match_all": {
                        "type": "object"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "match_all": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          "source": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {
              "post": {
                "dynamic": "true",
                "properties": {
                  "_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "base_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "blog": {
            "properties": {
              "post": {
                "properties": {
                  "_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "notes": {
                    "properties": {
                      "main": {
                        "properties": {
                          "id": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "category": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "cart": {
                        "properties": {
                          "id": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "message": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "category": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bool query with must on ids and terms

```
POST c1_2/Test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              1,
              2,
              3
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "blog.post.notes.main.category": [
              "categoryfilter"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But since you have main and cart categories you must use filter on each of them, in my example i filter on main categories, if you need to do filter on both you need to use one more or filter which will filter on main or cart categories

Also you should know that category should be not_analyzed in order to filter on something like "my super category" other wise query will not be working properly.

Example

```
POST c1_2/Blog/1
{
  "post": {
    "notes": {
      "main": [
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "test"
        },
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "other"
        }
      ],
      "cart": [
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "test"
        },
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "other"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

POST c1_2/Blog/2
{
  "post": {
    "notes": {
      "main": [
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "second"
        },
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "third"
        }
      ],
      "cart": [
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "test"
        },
        {
          "message": "blablabla",
          "category": "other"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


POST c1_2/Blog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [
              1,
              2,
              3
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "post.notes.main.category": [
              "test"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate, I tried to add this both in filter and query section but it returns 0 hits for any category, anyway I will mark your answer as correct if no other cues.

Comment: Well i tried this query before post it must works. can you copy query which you use?

Comment: 'category' is in object that is in array in main, maybe have I bad mapping?

Comment: Actually mapping are right. Which category value you try to filter?

Comment: I just added example. it will add you new index, so just try if it works

Comment: Your examples works, so I have to verify my real world data, thanks for tutorial.

Comment: Last question can I get results by ids, than filter nested notes by category, but hide not matched categories? So if category is `test` then hide `other` from notes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105150/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-leon).